# How do I restore the title bar button arrangement to its original style in GNOME?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool, titlebar, window-buttons

I recently installed the Pantheon DE to test out, and wasn't too fond of it so I switched back to GNOME. However, even after uninstalling Pantheon, window title bars are still using the Pantheon style.

[image: This screenshot is my title bar right now.]

How do I revert this change?

I've tried changing the theme in GNOME Tweak Tool, as well as resetting GNOME entirely, but it won't reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

This should fix the order and placement of the buttons.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, but so far this solution hasn't worked.
Just relogged to see if it fixes it.